# Discord bot with yfinance, attribute error

Tags: python

I've been making a discord bot with discord.py recently with the intent of using it to provide stock info on command.

I've been able to use TA_handler.py and discord.py with no problems but when I wanted to use yfinance to pull info from yahoo finance I got the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'floatShares'`

Edit: Forgot to mention but it goes without saying that everything is imported, I just didn't include that in the post

I get this no matter what I attempt to use on the ticker and no matter what fashion I try to use it, for example I made this smaller test command to display on here:

```
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.content == m.content and m.channel == message.channel
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    obj = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
    obj_display = obj.floatShares
    await message.channel.send("{}".format(obj_display))

#This displays the error and I have no idea how I'm using it improperly, here is my other main example:

@client.command(name = "float")
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.content == m.content and m.channel == message.channel
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await message.channel.send('Please input a ticker')
    tGrab = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout =30)
    tGrab = tGrab.content
    obj = yf.Ticker(tGrab)
    obj_Display = obj.floatShares
    await message.channel.send("{}".format(obj_Display))
```

Comment: I see no mention of `floatShares` in [`yfinance.Ticker`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/ticker.py). What makes you think that variable should be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm kind of an idiot but I figured it out, so you have to grab the entire info summary on the stock first before you can grab specific values, very odd but it is what it is.

Here is the example code for AAPL but working properly:

```
@client.command(name = "t")
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.content == m.content and m.channel == message.channel
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    obj = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
    obj_infograb = obj.info
    floatgrab = obj_infograb['floatShares']
    await message.channel.send("{}".format(floatgrab))
```